# Providing path to proj4 to rgdal in R

Tags: r, rgdal

I have proj4 version 4.9.2 installed in a non-standard location within a Linux environment (/p/bin/proj4). I know that proj_def.dat did not go out with version 4.9.1, but was of the understanding that it was included in version 4.9.2. I have verified that it works, I have added /p/bin/proj4/share/proj to my PATH. In addition, I downloaded the [datum shifting files](ftp://ftp.remotesensing.org/pub/proj/proj-datumgrid-1.4.zip) for North America to proj/conus. When I run R and load `rgdal`, I receive the message that Path to PROJ.4 shared files is autodetected. This is in contrast to gdal, which shows the correct path to my installation of gdal. I provided the following argument when I installed `rgdal` "--with-proj-share=/p/bin/proj 4/share/proj".

However, when I run `raster()`, I receive the following message:

> rgdal::checkCRSArgs:: no proj_defs.dat in PROJ.4 shared files

I have verified that there is a proj_def.dat in proj/ folder.

Is their an argument that I can provide when loading `rgdal` that will point to the proj_defs.dat files.

Comment: Have you tried installing `rgdal` and including the option `with-proj-lib=/p/bin/proj4/lib' ?

Comment: yes, I also added '--with-proj-include=/p/bin/proj4/include'

Comment: Check [here](https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4/issues/351) for further details

Comment: I am currently using proj4 version 4.9.2, which theoretically solves the problem. In my case, it doesn't. I think that the answer is somewhere in the configure file for rgdal,